# Did the New York Times publish an article in 1945 saying "1,000,000 to 1,500,000 of Europe's 6,000,000 Jews were now left on the Continent"?

Tags: holocaust

The following image is [widely circulated](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisOjG7RYx_1KsTZCUDDC8c2qa6KC3LbfN9DWgxlrCW6EXreDrvGXf5sQXBEXs0JtYgQbUhV2Yu1OpEIGKIHS8Zghtb90D2I2lNm1wqoTYWZzWGfnbkwRR6v7dzhhjS4YPhNHdr6IhPdikvf607PAFxCr_1InghhQCiRSkypcethRUCg8HYGoX5jYJ_1wbKWZjYwg19Um7hn2KdTHjWYXnyNSF_1j0zJEs9CvbYCLkTU2MoFBDEmjI1ftEy2nQMfM34DAFgN00XUWNFUbHGtQqVpsfKSWuBX3KCXhbGjgmMV1hC1eOvWstQUbHdUYGoNggW3Wds3nJIzSOSAbgfsmmkFvuG_1YQve9b_1bvd_1KoHigGbuwwJ2J_11tZyNutvckHjN93-XfiKEkj6HJLHBzU9L483vAtbTpCZyu5B98KNdhso4Xz6frELDU60ol2mEyrm8ru7oEkmW30IW64f4nDeChEhh4vAElJkcWCPovXhx_181iyB8BESif6jzmauYyeJFkWLppUYCu9e1CtFNwuNaRAGZW4XiNu1EnXcpRIniPU70bWH-Jb3S_1e7wTvP6tGGJB-bEbdIOisWnAPsNLJVuFM7wAeiw9dRoqJDqjfNY02kp-JUNV7UCPJIPqyV3l8iXZbfHWnvnv9ke1OXDBRiMHaGAEpCcpHanI473fTZkkv_1TQHCWgTYewiy05Q-MnL3ln2wQ9lYwXm-GBvxyRqVRtx2LljhZBFjLPfX3O8BGj--k7LYzYOzzC5rXQ4FCq4S1GwRjgbyMrH7jHsZI9_1XzStm12IXxC1YvMA-7UhpxzMDNZMB2hG54S0nbmKFQCPQWBneI08EMhUDrL91dlxT1N_1Ehlf2cSGIUSy9Iu0dM3cGQ_17lRiPvVIGOy1FYM7uFfYo93p22VOuMe7XYxFtVsOpoNvB1aFXEAWB9IgLot5xkudcSLytBI6GRznU6goRUZr1gP6Xe8AR8PeY13DGjL9XPjok5qKlh9KbgEZtDUcJ5jr1QvSkbMFU5iR0GoKrRLsc97mEx5yPW3c2CrtHSpi0XxUs6b6aDlfXLypQJgyDCYPsq08T9idhf35GJhaCFDQBuEDFuqNFVjfm6_1FOK6CkqExo2Lqhxw3yqzVRyQyip8daDlh6gp0N3gP9jdrW7-E27O13ew_1IYl5ary5vYCTypgDpe3AOsshVat_1PXHqWKcNPfu8L7zlUBt_1MWSrthlSBCyz9enks2UBTGZ8KDQdOk8Bk4fAIwUJxdbfpY_1WiwgEwebMbReM6nZ_1DHbGweGFqoPpGJkqmQSU4d2m0CrYH1ammh4mNne_1iUer9NwUFeKgU492Y-fpLxmlyHcEjwu53vFKccDdCNYVvQqhCNjG3k-OYseFzlfLxPnYcEl4KJbLnxRCYGBhZnb6NNY5WEoDqh-QFfoad4c085GD0Jk7qhZNvC6r2tFLcox0Kb13eCiNR3FVgvovzHirBMNR-RkYX54iJ234TxOkt4xrcQS4vQN0mhlPZtDZCjGAUBPPJndQ-O-on_1OsV0OVgATmpSZk3eqxeaWPB8vMeoeBFIcalas-Svtkz443oICcpMKhdUuRz5RYbzYRFLZWwFr1k-rH0GkqQzsecdgwarcwlsp8aJ6gXHdLGNq5wbckQp9YmhvYJVFHAL3srDb2QWgq3IyqPJmknmnNlfkvLAeGm8ZeUQLtKr79z_1iOyQefQrJxgnR4JnlJYHT05Vh7URA1eakRnFqI3YVk3QpwaKEXkBKY_1_1YrixufZZuw&ei=8uycWLj4B8fuvgT6l76QAQ&start=70&sa=N&biw=1360&bih=704) in many sites on the internet:

[image]

The image claims to show various New York Times articles about the holocaust. The last paragraph of the image says:

> Dr. Joseph Schwartz, European director of the American Jewish Joint Distribution Committee, estimated today that 500,000 of Europe's 6,000,000 Jews escaped destruction by emigration and that only 1,000,000 to 1,500,000 of Europe's 6,000,000 Jews were now left on the Continent.

Did the New York Times publish such article?

Comment: IIRC the New York Times has posted articles denying the Nazi holocaust, and Stalinist famines. Keep in mind it doesn't mean those events didn't happen.

Comment: I don't understand the point they're making. I guess they're trying to twist these headlines to support holocaust denial somehow, but I really don't see how? Why would it be remarkable that the word holocaust was used before "the" Holocaust? It's a word used to describe massacres of innocents since the middle ages. Likewise there were 11ths of September before "9/11". Just trying to understand the context of the claim.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it seems to me that the article in question suggests that four million to 4.5 million Jews had been "destroyed." That hardly counts as holocaust denial. If one wants to argue about numbers, keep in mind that the article was written a couple of months before the end of the war, so the documentary evidence that led to the normally cited figure of six million would not have been fully available. Furthermore, not all of the six million Jewish victims of the holocaust had yet perished.

Comment: @user568458 I don't see anything about when the word "Holocaust" was used.

Comment: @user568458 A staple of holocaust denial is challenging the number: that 6M (Jews, specificially) were executed systematically. This quoted claim seems to be saying that 6M is an impossible number, though it is the widely accepted one.

Comment: I'm not actually sure that the claim is notable as it stands. Did the NYT publish something: not very notable unless it is very specific. If it did publish it, quote the notable part and ask that question. Even then, rough numeric estimates at a time when the concentration camps were known about but no documentation from the camps or local pre-war demographics were well studied isn't the basis of a notable claim: the numbers were bound to be approximate.

Comment: Yes, we could do with a clarification of what is being claimed. Is it that 1,500,000 ish Jews were left in Europe at the end of the war,  that 500,000 emigrated or that 5,000,000 emigrated? The last one of those is obviously false, as the quoted newspaper shows. (The holocaust denial implicit in linking all those headlines from a 40 year range together is a different category of horse crap on the other hand)

Comment: @PhillS: The question is none of those. This is not a "X said Y. Is Y true?" question. This is a meta-level "X said Y said Z. Did Y say Z?" question.

Comment: Just a comment. The second to last article "6000000 Jews Dead" was published even before the leberation of Auschwitz, it would be hard to impossible to get an acurate astimation of the total number killed at such a stage.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the article title was [Schwartz Says Only 1,500,000 Jews Are Left In Europe as Result of German Murder](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9E01E6DB153FE532A05754C1A9649C946493D6CF&legacy=true). The article was on page 8 of Feb 17<sup>th</sup>, 1945, issue of the newspaper.

There is also a large collection of Holocaust related headlines available here: https://www.historiography-project.com/lindsey/nyt/index.php

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Why did you choose the 14th?

Comment: I misspelled, it's the 17.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed you must be looking forward to Valentine's Day.